# Sci Fi short story about anything being possible

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for the title of a short story that I think was in an anthology book.  I read it a little over ten years ago now but I have a habit of visiting used bookstores as well as newer stores such as Barnes and Noble so it really could have been written in any year. It was about a woman interviewing a man about why he is in self imposed exile on the moon.  He tells her that a long time ago another astronaut went crazy and took off in a rover but somehow survived for several days after his oxygen should have run out.  The man then reveals that the original group learned that you can do anything but humans are taught from a young age that certain things are impossible and this holds us back.

Comment: Any idea how old the anthology was? 5 years, 20 years, 50 years?

Comment: I don't remember how old it was.

Comment: Well, about how long ago did you read it?

Comment: Well I read it a little over ten years ago now but I have a habit of visiting used bookstores as well as newer stores such as Barnes and Noble so it really could have been written in any year.

Comment: You could write that it's at least 10 years old, that'll narrow it down too

Answer (score 1):

Did the person going crazy hallucinate a farmhouse with an old couple living on the moon? If so it might be "Sunday Night Yams at Minnie and Earls" by Adam-Troy Castro.
[Variety SF Sunday Night Yams](http://variety-sf.blogspot.ca/2007/09/adam-troy-castros-sunday-night-yams-at.html)